# Customizing Log report - ACRA Android

Tags: android, acra

I am using ACRA for android app like this

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "dEpU12345lRZYjFtOUxMVHl4MFpMdnc6MQ",  mailTo = "issues@xyz.com",
    customReportContent = { ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA, ReportField.STACK_TRACE, ReportField.LOGCAT },                
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
    resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)
```

it is perfectly sending crash report along with Log cat. It is sending all last 200 lines of logcat with date by default.But I want to customize it to send only last 100 log cat messages of my app with log levels i or d. How to do it.

By following below link

https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#adding-logcat-eventlog-or-radiolog-extracts-to-reports

I made changes like this

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "dEpU12345lRZYjFtOUxMVHl4MFpMdnc6MQ",  mailTo = "issues@xyz.com",
    customReportContent = { ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA, ReportField.STACK_TRACE, ReportField.LOGCAT },
    logcatArguments = { "-t", "100", "-v", "long","test:I" ,"*:D","*:S"},        
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
    resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)
```

even though I printed some log messages with tag "test" and level "i", and manged them to print before my known crash in my app, I am getting empty logcat. I want log messages of only my app with level i or d with ACRA, how to achieve this. Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2):

The below works for me for D level logging. My proguard strips V and I levels for production deployemnts. I am using the following code to update the log

```
Log.d("YOUR_TAG_HERE", "Some message here");
```

and the ACRA configuration is

```
logcatArguments = { "-t", "200", "-v", "long", "ActivityManager:I", "YOUR_TAG_HERE:D", "*:S" }
```

and don't forget to update your AndroidManifest.xml file adding the necessary permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

I was having troubles with my library project and my READ_LOGS permission was missing. I was getting random results until I added the READ_LOGS permission to the final project (not the library project).